# Error message while updating Ubuntu 20.04 from the terminal

Tags: package-management, 20.04, updates

I got the following error message when trying to update Ubuntu 20.04 with `sudo apt update`.

```
Err:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Err:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mefrio-g/plymouthmanager/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Err:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/vantuz/cool-retro-term/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mefrio-g/plymouthmanager/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/vantuz/cool-retro-term/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: You have multiple outdated repositories added. Run `sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:me-davidsansome/clementine`, `sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:mefrio-g/plymouthmanager` and finally `sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:vantuz/cool-retro-term`. Retry running `sudo apt update`. Also, please don't replace the error message text with the screenshot of the terminal unless there's some other error. Photos are slower to load and one cannot copy text from it.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I am new to Ubuntu and this solved my problem. I have few move questions which I cannot find on web and I will post it on here. Thank you so much buddy!!